# What is じゃけぇ supposed to mean?

Tags: translation, dialects

I came across this in a manga and can't figure out the meaning. I bet it's mainly used in casual conversation since the protagonist uses it during a conversation with his mother. But other than that, I don't get it at all.

It's used in this sentence:

> 知らんがー　落ちたモンは　落ちたんじゃけぇ

His mother is basically saying something like: *"You sounded so confident! Why didn't you get the job? Why?"* and he replies with that sentence.

I know 落ちる is "to fall" but I've never seen this kind of sentence either. I didn't find any information about it here or anywhere else either. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

edit: The manga is ReLife and the last え is small in the original sentence.

Comment: As me being Hiroshiman, I can't just ignore this post. Let me answer or add more explanations on lelectur's answer later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only 「じゃけぇ」 that I am familiar with is that used in Hiroshima dialect meaning 「だから」 and it is ***very often*** used at the ends of sentences.

When used at the end of a sentence, it just means "***alright?***" in the sense of "you hear?".  This is the exact same with 「じゃけぇ」 in Hiroshima dialect and 「だから」 in Standard Japanese.

Whether or not 「じゃけぇ」 is used in other areas, I have no knowledge.  I am from nowhere near Hiroshima myself.

「落{お}ちる」 here means "***to fail (in a job application screening)***".

> "Dunno..  I failed; I just failed, alright?"

A sign saying roughly "Gotta root for the Carp because I'm from Hiroshima!".  The Hiroshima Carp are a professional baseball team.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ameba.jp](http://stat.ameba.jp/user_images/20160901/11/kimura-maquereau/76/9c/j/o0480015213737493384.jpg?caw=800))</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! That cleared up a lot of question marks! :)

Comment: The signage is set just by the railroads so the message is towards the  passengers. As I will explain about じゃけぇ/じゃけん later じゃけぇ itself can be interpreted as several meanings. The signage is also readable in many ways. 'When it comes to Hiroshima, reminds you of Carp, doesn't it? this interpretation sounds best to me.

Answer (score 6):

> 知らんがー　落ちたモンは　落ちたんじゃけえ

It can be:

> 知らないけど落ちたものは落ちたんだから

<sup>じゃけえ is a dialect of Hiroshima.</sup>
The meaning is the same as だから.
So じゃけえ means **because**).

落ちた - In this case, this doesn't mean "to fall". This means failed getting the job.

Answer (score 4):

As I was grown up in Hiroshima,
I'm native to Hiroshima dialect which is known for its rough and provoking wording.

Let me add explanations about practical use of じゃけぇ/じゃけん(both are totally same) among Hiroshimans on Mr. electeur's answer.

じゃけぇ is composed of two particles:

assertive particle じゃ+ conjunction けぇ.

Its composition is same as だから.

However in Hiroshima dialect, we use じゃけぇ/じゃけん in many situations.

1. Conjunction

e.g. 'カープが負けとん**じゃけん**もっと応援せんにゃいけんのう。'

StJ 'カープが負けているの**だから**もっと応援しないといけないね。'

Eng 'We better root more **cuz** Carp is behind'

In this usage, じゃけぇ is same as だから.
I have to note that じゃけぇ and だから is used when speaker want to stress the conditional clause.
So じゃorだ is not necessary if the speaker doesn't care much about Carp's being behind.

2. Assertive particle

e.g. 'わしゃカープファン**じゃけぇ**。'

StJ '私はカープファン**です**。'

Eng '**I am** a Carp fan.' or 'I'm crazy about Carp.'

Note: Carp fans are famous/notorious for its crazy enthusiasm  towards the team.

3. Interjection

e.g. 'じゃけぇ！何しよん？'

StJ 'もう！何をしているのか？'

Eng 'Hey!(Oi!) what the f are you doing?'

Depending on speakers' tone, this じゃけぇ is often regarded as an offensive interjection.

Above 3 usages of じゃけぇ are often heard in Hiroshima dialect.

Let's move on to the sentence in the question.

'知らんがー 落ちたモンは 落ちたんじゃけぇ'

As for the state verb '知らんがー', in the actual plot, he is asked why he failed.
Thus '知らんがー' must connote anger or bad temper.
Translation would be ' I don't f care!' in the context.

As for '落ちたモンは 落ちたんじゃけぇ' part,
I assume this じゃけぇ is simply an assertive particle like above example 2.

落ちる means fail. Thats correct.

So I would like to translate the sentence.

'I don't f care! Fail is a fail.'

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it further, it helps me out a lot!